# ITMS-90284 invalid code signing with Mac Catalyst app

Tags: ios, mac-catalyst

When I try to upload my Mac Catalyst app to the Mac App Store it sends me the emAil:

> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, Drive Focus 2.0.6 (15). Please correct the following issues, then upload again. ITMS-90284: Invalid Code Signing - The executable DriveFocus2.0.app/Contents/Frameworks/MBCircularProgressBar.framework/Versions/A/Resources/MBCircularProgressBar.bundle must be signed with the certificate that is contained in the provisioning profile.

When I try to submit my app to the App Store for Mac Catalyst I get code signing error below. I have no idea how to solve the problem. I have googled everything I found and couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I will do my best with the information given. The steps I would take to debug and fix this issue would be:

1. Make sure MBCircularProgressBar.bundle is codesigned and with the same certificate that you used to codesign the rest of the app using the terminal codesign command
2. In your project go to the navigator click on the framework in question, MBCircularProgressBar, then go to the inspector on the right and make sure the Location is set to the proper location.
3. Open your pods.xcodeproj in the navigator click on Pods then under TARGETS click MBCircularProgressBar and go to Signing & Capabilities and if it selected deselect it and try, if it is not selected select it and follow the prompts

I hope this helps, ask questions if you have any.